# SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id'

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I got an error after trying to migrate.
And I didn't make any changes in other pages.

Every tables created as migrate default but it did not create my articles table.

This is the error that I got in CMD:
SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id'

And this is my _create_articles_table.php page:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateArticlesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->boolean('status');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('articles');
    }
}
```

and this is my AppServiceProvider page:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Schema;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        
    }

}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: doing `$table->id();` is equivalent to `$table->increments('id');` so no need to do it twice. remove one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, you are defining `id` column twice, no need to add this line:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

This will make it with auto-increment by default:

```
$table->id();
```

Answer (score 1):

> CMD: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id '

That means your id field is defined twice in the migration query so remove this line in your **articles**.

```
$table->increments('id');
```

Then migrate your table it is run.